# Having trouble with this method, compilation error

Tags: java

I'm getting an error in line 21 "cannot find symbol symbol method quickSort(int[], int, int), and I'm not sure why it's happening.

```
import java.util.Random;

  public class timeQuickSort {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      int size = 16;
      int max = 10;
      int[] array = new int[size];

      Random random = new Random();

      random.nextInt(max);

      for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
          array[i] = random.nextInt(max);
      }  

      long result;

      long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      quickSort(array,  100,  array.length-1);

      long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      result = endTime-startTime; 

      System.out.println("The quick sort runtime is " + result + " miliseconds");
  }
}
```

This is my quickSort method:

```
  public static void quickSort(int[] a, int p, int r)
  {
    if (p < r)
    {
      int q = partition(a,p,r);
      quickSort(a,p,q);
      quickSort(a,q+1,r);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where is the method located?

Comment: Just because it's static, doesn't mean it's accessible from another class without fully qualifying the call with the name of the class in which it resides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is declared in another class, then you need to invoke it by explicitly using the other classes name.

So, if the other class is called, say, `Sorter`, you just need to call

```
Sorter.quicksort(a, p, q);
Sorter.quicksort(a, q+1, r);
```

Comment: No worries, at times we all miss the obvious. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Specify class name to call static method if it resides in other class than current class.
like:

```
class Sort{
  public static void quickSort(int[] a, int p, int r)
  {
    if (p < r)
    {
    int q = partition(a,p,r);
    quickSort(a,p,q);
    quickSort(a,q+1,r);
    }
  }
}
```

and call it in your class like this:

```
    Sort.quickSort(array,  100,  array.length-1);
```